# Call a function on a list

Tags: data

I have a list that looks like

```
dataset = {"OPONJL", "BGMUAR", "MGBYCG", "TTRNPX", "KGUTXS", "HXHDMG", 
"CKIVIC", "DWZIVR", "GBEOCI", "ZGEEOV", "JMSIRY", "GWFUBH", "ODCWLR", 
"TCGKBB", "PHVKDH", "MUWQLC", "PDDSSC", "DJXOHH", "SJCVEW", "XLIAFN", 
"BMBMNT", "MHOOII", "IIKTRA"}
```

My goal is to call the function WordFrequencyData on such a list and produce a list containing the output. I first tried using the Select function but nothing seems to output:

Select[dataset, WordFrequencyData]

How do I go from here?

Comment: try `WordFrequencyData[dataset]`

Comment: You want to [Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) your list over a function.

Comment: Trying WordFrequencyData[dataset] gives me an error. I think the issue could be that the function WordFrequencyData takes in a list containing a String rather than just a string itself. If this is so, how would I do this?

Comment: It works fine on actual words... try `WordFrequencyData[{"OPEN","JAR"}]` and you will get  `<|OPEN->5.928*10^-7,JAR->1.03354*10^-7|>`. If you don't get this result then something is wrong